# Custom template for WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I am trying to make up a WPF datagrid custom item template. The image for that is the following:

http://postimg.org/image/457tyzba1/

But I have not idea yet about how to create custom item controls :( Please, help me to do that. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if this site helps you. (http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

Comment: @voddy thx, but that article does not describe the basic thing i want to do: how to make a datarow as stack panel, when each column of datarow is placed below the previous.